# Prove that a function is $\ C^1 $ in all its domain

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have the following function:

$\ f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} $

I need to prove it is $\ C^1$ in all its domain, that is, all partial derivatives of $\ f$ exist and they're continuous

What I did:

I showed that 
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{y}{x^2} = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^2y}$$ 
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{y^2} = \frac{-x^2 + y^2}{xy^2}$$

From that, it is clear that $\ f$ is $\ C^1$ in all its domain except at $\ x=0$ or $\ y=0$, but I got stuck while proving that the partial derivatives of $\ f$ are not continuous at $\ x=0$ or $\ y=0$

Any ideas?

Comment: x=0 and y=0 aren't in the domain so you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: You're right, but I think I still need to prove that the partial derivatives are continuous except at x=0 or y=0. How can I dot this?

Comment: Rational functions are continuous at any point where the denominator is nonzero.